# Visit my site but nothing appears (totally blank with no error message)

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2

I host a WordPress site on Amazon EC2 (Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS), and everything works fine. However, now, nothing appears (no error, totally blank) on a web browser while I visit my site.

I tried the following steps to find out what is going on with my site.

Ping is OK.

```
$ ping example.com
...
--- example.com ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 61.167/66.547/73.538/4.035 ms
```

MySQL works fine.

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
[ ok ] Starting mysql (via systemctl): mysql.service.
```

Apache works fine as well.

```
$ sudo netstat -anp | grep apache
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      2485/apache2        
tcp6       0      0 172.31.24.13:80         148.64.56.123:50947     ESTABLISHED 2496/apache2
```

More specifically,

```
$ sudo systemctl status apache2
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2020-03-08 12:49:16 UTC; 3min 58s ago
  Process: 2463 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/apachectl stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2469 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2485 (apache2)
    Tasks: 27 (limit: 2315)
   CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
           ├─2485 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─2564 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

           └─2645 [stealth]

Mar 08 12:49:15 ip-172-31-24-13 systemd[1]: Stopped The Apache HTTP Server.
Mar 08 12:49:15 ip-172-31-24-13 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Mar 08 12:49:16 ip-172-31-24-13 systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Checked `/var/log/syslog`,

```
Mar  8 13:33:01 ip-172-31-24-13 CRON[4178]: (www-data) CMD (/var/www/qiankun.su/S0GF7x  > /dev/null 2>&1)
Mar  8 13:33:08 ip-172-31-24-13 systemd-resolved[777]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
```

I followed the instructions from [Ubuntu 18.04 systemd-resolved error NXDOMAIN - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1115882/ubuntu-18-04-systemd-resolved-error-nxdomain) and solved the above problem with,

```
$ sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
$ sudo ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
$ sudo systemctl restart resolvconf
```

With the help of @Steve, I found there is an empty `index.html` under my site.

```
0 -rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data   0 Mar  9 06:46 index.html
4 -rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu   www-pub  420 Mar  7 05:08 index.php
```

I delete it. Everything is back to normal.

Unfortunately, after somewhile, the problem reproduces. What can I do next to find out the problem?

Comment: You said "totally blank".  I assume you've used Developer Console in your browser to look at network traffic and the raw html?  Any clues from the client side?

Comment: @Trebor, I made it by deleting the empty file `index.html` under my site.

Comment: Are you saying the index.html was recreated?  If so, then you can do 2 things:  Firstly you should find out what is creating the file.  Secondly you can change the index file priority so that if it exists index.php is loaded before index.html - here is one method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322345/how-do-i-change-the-default-index-page-in-apache

Comment: @Steve, yes, the `index.html` was recreated. Add `DirectoryIndex index.php` to `.htaccess`. It works again. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem pretty knowledgeable, have you disabled .htaccess?

Tried a dummy index.php with just something like "test" and nothing else so you can see if you are actually reaching the site? (That's the first thing I would do)

Checked error_log?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning it. There is an empty `index.html` under my site. I delete it. Everything is back to normal.